# How to reduce the ambient noise for AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, audio, recorder

I'm making a Mac app that allows users to record audio. When I playback the audio, the audio has ambient noise and I don't know how to reduce it like in Settings--- Sound--- Use ambient noise reduction. I would like to have a checkbox button in my app to do it. My settings for AVAudioRecorder are:

```
// Settings for the recorder

NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

NSError *error;
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedAudioURL settings:recordSetting error:&error];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
```